# How to install and use db4o for Android?

Tags: java, android, persistence, db4o

I have to admit that I'm new to Java and Android. db4o seems to be an excellent DB framework to replace SQLite http://developer.db4o.com/Platforms/Java/Android.aspx. I want to use it for my Android application. I don't know how to: Import/Install/Attach/Upload db4o to Android phone. Where should I put the JAR file db4o-7.12.132.14217-all-java5.jar so that it was uploaded to Android phone and it could be called from the application? Please kindly advise! Many thanks!!!

### EDIT

In addition to the answer, here goes the official documentation:
http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.4/net2/reference/html/reference/platform_specific_issues/android.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it anywhere you like, maybe make a new directory 'libs' in your application root and add it there. Then go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add External JARs, and select this file.

The imports should now work. Eclipse will prompt you with the lightbulb in the left margin when you start using the classes, to add an import automatically.